# What unresolvable IP address should I use to block adverts?

Tags: ip, blocking, hosts

I don't want to depend solely on in-browser ad blockers. I therefore created my own block list of advertisers' domains and pointed them all to a `0.0.0.0` IP address.

I now started a project and need to do some local development on port 80. I found however when I browse sites while doing development I am getting error messages in the log files.

What is the canonical way to do such things - what quick and unresolvable IP addresses can I point to?

*If you are interested [here is my list](https://gist.github.com/882184).*

Comment: Why didn't you just use the loopback ip, 127.0.0.1?

Comment: why am I not surpirsed to see mgid.com in there >_<

Comment: @Rob 127.0.0.1 is actually the same and point same host as 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use 254.254.254.254. He can't use 127.0.0.1 because he said he has a webserver on his system already. Although I kinda wonder if you could point themto something dumb like 356.0.0.0?

Comment: He could run the webserver from a different than standard port, as he said it's local development.

Comment: @Rob True, true...

Comment: I cann't there is some story behind, sure 80 is not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of premade, more complete lists available online.

http://rlwpx.free.fr/WPFF/hosts.htm

http://pgl.yoyo.org/as/serverlist.php?hostformat=hosts;showintro=0

http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.txt

Answer (score 0):

Just a note that you can set the IP address used with my list by using the "useip" query string parameter. eg:

http://pgl.yoyo.org/as/serverlist.php?hostformat=hosts;showintro=0&useip=0.0.0.0